# how do you model a transmission line at dc?

Tags: transmission-line

how do you model a transmission line at dc?

Comment: You don't. Transmission lines are all about transient effects.

Comment: A resistor, I guess.

Comment: right so its just a wire at DC?

Comment: A real wire has RLC.

Comment: yeah yeah I'm talking ideal model

Comment: Is this a random thought or is there somewhere you want to go with this-a problem you're trying to understand or fix?

Comment: 0ohm resistor, ideal model

Answer (score 1):

A transmission line at DC is modelled as two resistances, each calculated from the length, gauge and resistivity of its conductors.

Often it is specified as R per length, e.g. 10 Ohm per 1000 feet. With coax, the core (or center) will have a different R-per-distance than the shell, due to the difference in cross sectional conductive area of each.

Here's an example for coax:

[image]

From http://www.dbsinstall.com/diy/CoaxCableTypes.asp

As an aside, transmission lines  are often also used to *supply power* in tandem with communication signals.

DC is then the mode of choice over AC for power supply, since the lines distributed L and C will have no effect on impedance matching or power losses, and only the R matters. It can be measured with an Ohm meter.

That same R forms the basis for the line's attenuation, although with increasing frequency the R increases because the currents flow in a smaller (outer shell) cross section of the conductor due to "skin effect" which worsens as f increases.

Moreover, the signal is AC coupled, and the power is DC coupled with a throttle for higher frequencies.